# ActionBar color does not change on 2.3.3

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application that targets the min. SDK version of 9. I'm trying to set the color of the action bar, and it does change on a Lollipop device, but not on a 2.3.3 device.

Following the instructions from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground), I've set up the custom theme in the manifest:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" ...>
```

And here's the themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/my_orange</item>
        <item name="background">@color/my_orange</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The 2.3.3 phone shows the theme otherwise correctly; the light theme is applied with a dark action bar. However, the custom color is not applied.

Comment: please provide your appcomat library version

Comment: @PatriX1996 I'm using the v7 appcompat support library, ver. 22.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different styles for different API version. Create new folder with the name of values-v11, and move your file themes.xml there. 
Then, create a new themes.xml file in the folder values and put there this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="AppTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="AppActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```